# Repeat the number of rows in mysql based upon a column

Tags: mysql

Good morning
I have a table like below which I have to repeat the based upon the "DT1-Increased_Reason" column entries.

```
Region  Market  Cluster         Report_Name     DT1-Increased_Reason
abc     CT      NECTC11123      NECTC11         TMO_Waiting For Report/Recommendations     Approval;#ERIC_Delay between Start to Submit. Refer to DT1-Increased CT Reason (Start to Submit);#
def     LA      GCR_OPT_WELA                    TMO_Waiting For Report/Recommendations Approval;#
abc     NJ      NENJC086567     Westchester_02  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives;#ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning;#
```

You can observe that entries in "DT1-Increased_Reason" column have multiple using "#;"

My desired data is

```
Region  Market  Cluster         Report Name     DT1-Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept
abc     CT      NECTC11123      NECTC11         TMO_Waiting For Report/Recommendations Approval
abc     CT      NECTC11123      NECTC11         ERIC_Delay between Start to Submit. Refer to DT1-Increased CT Reason (Start to Submit)
def     LA      GCR_OPT_WELA        TMO_Waiting For Report/Recommendations Approval;#
abc     NJ      NENJC086567     Westchester_02  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long
abc     NJ      NENJC086567     Westchester_02  ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives
abc     NJ      NENJC086567     Westchester_02  ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning;#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number, you can do this as:

```
select t.Region, t.Market, t.Cluster, t.ReportName,
       substring_index(DT1_Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept, ';#', 1)
from t 
union all
select t.Region, t.Market, t.Cluster, t.ReportName,       
      substring_index(substring_index(DT1_Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept, ';#', 2), ';#', -1)
from t 
where DT1_Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept like '%;#_%'
union all
select t.Region, t.Market, t.Cluster, t.ReportName,       
      substring_index(substring_index(DT1_Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept, ';#', 3), ';#', -1)
from t 
where DT1_Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept like '%;#%;#_%';
```

You would add another subquery for each additional reason.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Its not working... I am trying, its giving the same result like select * from table, not dividing by ;#

Comment: @user2503377 . . . The delimiter wasn't quite correct.